# BST element ordering

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

In a BST (binary search tree), can *any* element to the right of the root node be *smaller* than the root node?

Ie, root is 4, right child is 10, then the left child of that right child is -234

Is it possible/allowed in the definition?

Answer (score 2):

No. See [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

> A binary search tree is a rooted binary tree, whose internal nodes each store a key (and optionally, an associated value) and each have two distinguished sub-trees, commonly denoted left and right. The tree additionally satisfies the binary search property, which states that **the key in each node must be greater than or equal to any key stored in the left sub-tree, and less than or equal to any key stored in the right sub-tree**.

When you arrive at some, say it contains value 4, and you want to find node with value -234, you always go to the left and if you want to find a node with value 10 you always go to the right.